# Mongo ODM @Collection Annotation Usage

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, odm

I am unsure on how to use the @Collection annotation in Mongo. As you know, I am trying to save a simple array in a Mongo document.

So in my document:

```
 /**
     * @MongoDB\Collection
     */
    protected $counties = array();



/**
     * Set counties
     *
     * @param collection $counties
     * @return self
     */
    public function setCounties($counties)
    {
        $this->counties = $counties;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get counties
     *
     * @return collection $counties
     */
    public function getCounties()
    {
        return $this->counties;
    }
```

Now when I go to save something for example:

```
$county = "test entry"
    $obj = new Obj();
    $obj->setCounties(array($county));
```

It now gives me warning "expected collection, got array".

How come?

Comment: Hello, you can use ArrayCollection to handle your data, hope that will help?